# rpm runtime error due to faulty spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, sles, specfile

I have a spec file in which based on the SLES version, i need to change the 'Requires: ' tag as below

```
#if suse is greated than SLES 11 sp4
%if %0{?suse_version} > 1140 
Requires: genisoimage
%else 
Requires: mkisofs 
%endif
```

I am building this rpm file on a SLES 10 machine. After generating RPM, irrespective of the OS, if i run,

> rpm -qpR mypkg.rpm

I get mkisofs only as a required package. In none if the cases (even on SLES 12), I am getting genisoimage as dependent package.

What might be missing and how can this be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how this works. This variable is evaluated at build-time, not at install time.

> This macro expands to the version of SUSE Linux / openSUSE **where the package is built**. It is "1000" for SUSE Linux 10.0, "1020" for openSUSE 10.2 and so on.

emphasis mine, [source](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Packaging_Conventions_RPM_Macros#.25suse_version)

Also, as far as I understand, this variable refers only to the OpenSUSE version, not the SLES base version and SP anyway, so it wouldn't be present at all during build time on a SLES 10 machine.

Comment: Right @Sven. So is there a way, i can check that at run time ?

Comment: The proper approach is to build different packages for different OSes.

Comment: Thanks @Sven. Although that is the right approach, for a patch work as we dont have a setup to create multiple packages, I have added a script under %pre and that script fetch for existed OS and based on the result, if it is an error, I am putting and exit 1 in the script and this is blocking the installation after displaying the error message.